# Android SQLite3 file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I am working on an app that pulls from a database a random line when the user hits a button.  I am using

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

as a database helper.  I have created a database with

http://sqlitebrowser.org/

and I have followed every instruction in the docs.  When I try to run the app, it crashes when i hit the button.  The button press brings up a new activity that is supposed to display the data.  When I pull the properties for the file, it is listed as a database.  Here is a selection from the logcat that shows the errors:

```
03-10 18:52:07.476  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke W/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ copying database from assets...
03-10 18:52:07.488  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke W/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ database copy complete
03-10 18:52:07.544  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/SQLiteLog﹕ (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
03-10 18:52:07.556  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke/databases/mankiniDB.db
03-10 18:52:07.556  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler﹕ deleting the database file: /data/data/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke/databases/mankiniDB.db
03-10 18:52:07.568  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30191 of [00bb9c9ce4]
03-10 18:52:07.568  10812-10812/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30191: (2) open(/data/data/tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke/databases/mankiniDB.db) -
```

It copies the database successfully, and then fails to open it.

This is the DB Helper Class:

```
package tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

/**
 * Created by TomandGina on 3/9/2015.
 */
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mankiniDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public Cursor kamikazeSelected() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM songList ORDER BY random () limit 1", null);

        return cursor;
    }
}
```

and here is the class that calls the database:

```
package tomschinler.thegreatman_kiniskamikazekaraoke;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;


public class SongActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);

        //when activity launches query database using user params

        TextView songTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        TextView songArtist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songArtist);
        TextView songYear = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songYear);

        db= new MyDatabase(this);


        Cursor cursor = db.kamikazeSelected();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            songTitle.setText(cursor.getString(2));
            songArtist.setText(cursor.getString(3));
            songYear.setText(cursor.getInt(4));
        }
        cursor.close();

    }
```

Edit:  I am adding the db file from the app:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE songList (
    `_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `Title` TEXT,
    `Artist`    TEXT,
    `Decade`    INTEGER,
    `Year`  INTEGER,
    `Genre` TEXT
);
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (1,'Great Balls of Fire','Jerry Lee Lewis',50,1957,'Rock');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (2,'Ring of Fire','Johnny Cash',60,1963,'Country');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (3,'Shaft','Shaft',70,1971,'Blues');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (4,'Hotel California','Eagles',70,1973,'Rock');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (5,'Take On Me','AHA',80,1985,'Pop');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (6,'Don''t Stop Believing','Journey',80,1981,'Rock');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (7,'Friends in Low Places','Garth Brooks',90,1991,'Country');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (8,'Baby Got Back','Sir Mix-A-Lot',90,1992,'Hip Hop');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (9,'Hey Ya','OutKast',0,2000,'Hip Hop');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (10,'I Kissed a Girl','Katy Perry',0,2007,'Pop');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (11,'Just the way you are','Bruno Mars',10,2010,'Pop');
INSERT INTO songList VALUES (12,'Super Bass','Nicki Minaj',10,2010,'Hip Hop');
CREATE TABLE android_metadata ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');
INSERT INTO android_metadata VALUES ('en_US');
COMMIT;
```

I have looked on Stack Overflow and become very familiar with Google, but I can not figure this out.  Please help.